# Proving two functions are equal.

Tags: functions

Given $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4}-1}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4}-1}}$ and $g(x)=x^4-4x^2+2$.

Prove that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$.

Comment: where do you have problems?

Comment: Why should they be equal?

Comment: Maybe the question needs to be re-worded to say: How can we prove that equality without extensive algebraic operations.

Comment: Yes, I do want to prove this problem using as few algebraic operations as possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*. By Cardano's formula, $f$ is invertible and
$$f^{-1} (y) = y^3 - 3y$$
Then call $y = f(x)$.